# Match string from column and pick preselected columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset and i want to take rows if a value match in code column and also take only preselected columns, maybe i'm not clear what i need please see the code below.

**This is my main dataframe:**

```
        code   des   price   year   brand test test1 test2
0      code1  des1  price1  year1  brand1   xx    xx    xx
1      code2  des2  price2  year2  brand2   xx    xx    xx
2      code3  des3  price3  year3  brand3   xx    xx    xx
3      code4  des4  price4  year4  brand4   xx    xx    xx
4      code5  des5  price5  year5  brand5   xx    xx    xx
5      code6  des6  price6  year6  brand6   xx    xx    xx
6    code114    xx      xx     xx      xx   xx   xxx    xx
7    code274    xx      xx     xx      xx   xx    xx    xx
8     code43    xx      xx     xx      xx   xx    xx    xx
9    code478    xx      xx     xx      xx   xx   xxx    xx
10   code565    xx      xx     xx      xx   xx    xx    xx
11  code6789    xx      xx     xx      xx   xx   xxx    xx
```

**These are the codes that i want to match and get that rows from main dataframe:**

```
['code1','code2','code3','code4','code114','code478','code6789']
```

**These are the colums that i want to get only:**

```
['des','price','brand','test1']
```

**This is my empty dataset where i want to keep the data after extract from main dataframe:**

```
    code des price year brand size test test1 test2
0
```

**This is what i want as output:**

```
       code   des   price year   brand size test test1 test2
0     code1  des1  price1       brand1              xx
1     code2  des2  price2       brand2              xx
2     code3  des3  price3       brand3              xx
3     code4  des4  price4       brand4              xx
4   code114    xx      xx           xx             xxx
5   code478    xx      xx           xx             xxx
6  code6789    xx      xx           xx             xxx
```

Here is the code i wrote so far, but can't understand how can i solve this, if someone help that would be great, thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



code = ['code1','code2','code3','code4','code114','code478','code6789']

columns = ['des','price','brand','test1']


source_data = {
'code': ['code1','code2','code3','code4','code5','code6','code114','code274','code43','code478','code565','code6789'],
'des': ['des1','des2','des3','des4','des5','des6','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx'],
'price': ['price1','price2','price3','price4','price5','price6','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx'],
'year': ['year1','year2','year3','year4','year5','year6','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx'],
'brand': ['brand1','brand2','brand3','brand4','brand5','brand6','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx'],
'test' : ['xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx'],
'test1' : ['xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xxx','xx','xx','xxx','xx','xxx'],
'test2' : ['xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx','xx'],
}


destination_data = {
'code': [''],
'des': [''],
'price': [''],
'year': [''],
'brand': [''],
'size': [''],
'test' : [''],
'test1' : [''],
'test2' : [''],
}


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(destination_data)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
to_match = ['code1','code2','code3','code4','code114','code478','code6789']
cols = ['code', 'des','price','brand','test1']

out = df.loc[df.code.isin(to_match), cols]
out = out.reindex(df.columns, axis=1).fillna('')
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
        code   des   price year   brand test test1 test2
0      code1  des1  price1       brand1         xx      
1      code2  des2  price2       brand2         xx      
2      code3  des3  price3       brand3         xx      
3      code4  des4  price4       brand4         xx      
6    code114    xx      xx           xx        xxx      
9    code478    xx      xx           xx        xxx
```

---

EDIT: Without the empty columns:

```py
to_match = ['code1','code2','code3','code4','code114','code478','code6789']
cols = ['code', 'des','price','brand','test1']

out = df.loc[df.code.isin(to_match), cols]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
        code   des   price   brand test1
0      code1  des1  price1  brand1    xx
1      code2  des2  price2  brand2    xx
2      code3  des3  price3  brand3    xx
3      code4  des4  price4  brand4    xx
6    code114    xx      xx      xx   xxx
9    code478    xx      xx      xx   xxx
11  code6789    xx      xx      xx   xxx
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i want to take only columns that in cols, is is possible?

Comment: @SohanDas You don't want the empty columns? So just don't `.reindex` the `out` dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the masking using `isin` method of the pandas Series, and take only the columns you want.

```py
df[df['code'].isin(['code1','code2','code3','code4','code114','code478','code6789'])][['des','price','brand','test1']]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
     des   price   brand test1
0   des1  price1  brand1    xx
1   des2  price2  brand2    xx
2   des3  price3  brand3    xx
3   des4  price4  brand4    xx
6     xx      xx      xx   xxx
9     xx      xx      xx   xxx
11    xx      xx      xx   xxx
```

Comment: these are already defined by op so `out=df[df['code'].isin(code)][columns]` will do the work and then `out=df.reindex(out.index)`